# R tsibble time series interpolation results in an error

Tags: r

When I run the following code to interpolate data on a time series, I receive this error:
Error in `transmute()`:
! Problem while computing `interpolated = map2(`ARIMA(IC)`, new_data, interpolate, ...)`.
Caused by error in `stats::KalmanSmooth()`:
! invalid argument type.

Here is my data and code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(writexl)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(feasts)    

WS_test <-structure(list(rptdate = structure(c(17532, 17622, 17713, 17805, 
    17897, 17987, 18078, 18170, 18262, 18353, 18444, 18536, 18628, 
    18718, 18809, 18901, 18993, 19083), fiscal_start = 1, class = c("yearquarter", 
    "vctrs_vctr")), IC = c(523L, 491L, 314L, 610L, 787L, 478L, 681L, 
    829L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 751L)), class = c("tbl_ts", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), key = structure(list(
        .rows = structure(list(1:18), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), index = structure("rptdate", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "rptdate", interval = structure(list(
        year = 0, quarter = 1, month = 0, week = 0, day = 0, hour = 0, 
        minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0, 
        nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), .regular = TRUE, class = c("interval", 
    "vctrs_rcrd", "vctrs_vctr")))
    
    WS <- WS_test %>% model(ARIMA(IC)) %>% interpolate(WS_test)
```

Any idea why this won't interpolate?

Comment: Can you edit and include the loaded libraries?

Comment: Edited to include libraries.

Comment: You also haven't included the `WS_remove_ts` object

Comment: Also `Initial_Claims_WS` is missing. 
On the other hand, it may be that `ARIMA` expects a formula

Comment: addressed the issue with WS_remove_ts and Initial_Claims_WS (copied an incorrect line). The error persist.